# Selenium Java Date Picker

Tags: java, selenium, datepicker

i am brand new here. Please excuse any weired questions.
I need to fill out a date in a webform. THe Form has a datepicker based on this HTML Code:
[image]

My Code is looking like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("FDD_Create_EntryDate")).sendKeys("26.02.2016");
```

I do assume this is not engough nor its working. 
I really appreciate your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Click on textbox so that datepicker will come  
  driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).click();  
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
 //Click on next so that we will be in next month  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("Pat to ur date picker")).click();  

 /*DatePicker is a table.So navigate to each cell   
 * If a particular cell matches value 13 then select it  
 */  
 WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.id("ui-datepicker-div"));  
List<webelement> rows=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));  
List<webelement> columns=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));  

for (WebElement cell: columns){  
 //Select 26 Date   
 if (cell.getText().equals("26")){  
 cell.findElement(By.linkText("13")).click();  
 break;  
 }  
 }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a cheeky solution, but could you just execute some javascript to make the date input field not readonly? Something like this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript
    (    
        "arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly');", 
        driver.findElement(By.id("FDD_Create_EntryDate"))
    );
driver.findElement(By.Id("FDD_Create_EntryDate")).sendKeys("26.02.2016");
```

This would require the correct format of the date being sent from the tester, but this could save you a lot of time if you don't care about testing the actual date widget.